# How to update the active state of a react-bootstrap nav link when I navigate to another route without using the link

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-context

I have a react app with an app like so:

```
function App() {
return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavContext.Provider value={{ activePage, onNavClick: handlePageChange }}>
          <Navbar2/>
          <div className="content">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}></Route>
              <Route path="/classes" element={<Classes/>}></Route>
              <Route path="/personal" element={<Personal/>}></Route>
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </NavContext.Provider>
        
      </div>
    </Router>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

A navbar like so:

```
const Navbar2 = () => {
const { activePage, onNavClick} = useContext(NavContext);

const handleClick2 = (newPage) => {
        console.log(newPage);
        onNavClick(newPage);
        console.log(activePage);
};

return (
        <Navbar expand="xxl" bg="primary" variant="dark">
            <Container fluid className="">
                <Nav>
                    <LinkContainer isActive={() => activePage === '/'} to="/" onClick={() => handleClick2('/')}>
                        <Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer end isActive={() => activePage === '/classes'} to="/Classes" onClick={() => handleClick2('/classes')}>
                        <Nav.Link>Classes</Nav.Link>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer end isActive={() => activePage === '/personal'} to="/Personal" onClick={() => handleClick2('/personal')}>
                        <Nav.Link >Personal</Nav.Link>
                    </LinkContainer>       
                </Nav>
                <Navbar.Brand>Almost Graduated</Navbar.Brand>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    );
}

export default Navbar2
```

and a home page like so:

```
const Home = () => {
    const fallClasses = ["class1", "class2", "class3", "class4"];
    const springClasses = ["class5", "class6", "class7", "class8", "class9"];
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const { onNavClick } = useContext(NavContext);

    const handleClick = () => {
        onNavClick('/classes');
        navigate('/classes');
    };

    return (
        <div className="home">
            <h2>Home</h2>
            <Container className="g-5">
                <Row className="g-5 fs-4">
                    <Col>
                        Some text
                    </Col>
                    <Col className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <Image src={logo} rounded />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className='mt-5'>
                    <Col>
                        <Card border="primary" style={{ height: '13rem' }} onClick={handleClick}>
                            <div className="row no-gutters h-100">
                                <div className="col-md-8">
                                    <Card.Body>
                                        <Card.Title>Fall</Card.Title>
                                        <Card.Text>
                                        <ul className="list-unstyled">
                                            {fallClasses.map((item) => (
                                                <li key={item}>{item}</li>
                                            ))}
                                        </ul>
                                    </Card.Text>
                                    </Card.Body>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-4">
                                    <Card.Img
                                        src={html_logo}
                                        alt="Placeholder"
                                        className="h-100"
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Card>
                        
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <Card border="primary" style={{ height: '13rem' }} onClick={handleClick}>
                            <div className="row no-gutters h-100">
                                <div className="col-md-8">
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <Card.Title>Spring</Card.Title>
                                    <Card.Text>
                                    <ul className="list-unstyled">
                                        {springClasses.map((item) => (
                                            <li key={item}>{item}</li>
                                        ))}
                                    </ul>
                                </Card.Text>
                                </Card.Body>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-4">
                                <Card.Img
                                    src={SVM}
                                    alt="Placeholder"
                                    className="h-100"
                                />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

My issue is that I am trying to set the active state of the navbar while when I navigate to my classes page while clicking one of the cards with `onClick={handleClick}`, instead of using the standard navigation.

With my current implementation while using contexts, I can update the active page which sets the classes nav link as active, but the home link still stays active as well. Is there a way I can mitigate this? I am currently trying to control the active state with isActivate, but there seems to be some sort of timing issue I cannot anticipate.